# Daemonised Bash script that stops or restarts only when condition is met

Tags: linux, bash, daemon

I have used the example in [this repository](https://github.com/wyhasany/sample-service-script/blob/master/service.sh) to demonise a bash script in Ubuntu 16.04.

The Daemon begins on startup, and behaves as expected in a Linux environment with commands such as:

```
service EXAMPLE_SERVICE start
service EXAMPLE_SERVICE stop
service EXAMPLE_SERVICE restart
```

The script is to process events from an event queue -the example below should give an idea, though the script itself is more complex.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    (php -f cli.php bash:v1:issueEvents)
    (php -f cli.php bash:v1:processSomeOrderAction)
    (php -f cli.php bash:v1:processSomeEquiryAction)
    sleep 10
done
```

What I would like to do is ensure the daemon is only able to exit during the sleep state.  Setting a Boolean variable `SAFE_TO_EXIT` is straightforward enough, but is there a way to ensure this condition is met before the process is manually restarted or stopped for instance by the operating system on reboot?

Comment: As an aside -- daemonization *really* shouldn't be done this way. Modern systems provide proper process supervision systems such as systemd or Upstart (or DJB daemontools, or runit, or s6, or supervisord, etc etc etc). A process supervision system will do this job better -- they don't have the failings of pidfiles (PIDs get reused, so just because a PID is still live, it doesn't mean it's associated with the same program it used to be), they get immediately notified if a process fails, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trap the signal used to request a shutdown, and handle it in the way you prefer.

Note that some signals can't be trapped -- if the daemonization script uses SIGKILL rather than SIGTERM, then you have no control over how the shutdown works. If it uses SIGTERM, however, you can handle it as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'stop=1' TERM

while true; do
    php -f cli.php bash:v1:issueEvents
    php -f cli.php bash:v1:processSomeOrderAction
    php -f cli.php bash:v1:processSomeEquiryAction
    [[ $stop ]] && break
    sleep 10
    [[ $stop ]] && break
done
```